# hopf algebra structure on tensor algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

The comultiplication on the tensor algebra $T(L)$ is defined as $\Delta(x) = x\boxtimes 1 + 1 \boxtimes y$ on 1-tensors (ie $x\in L$), where $\boxtimes$ is the tensor product appearing in $T(L) \boxtimes T(L)$ and $\otimes$ is the tensor product "internal" to $T(L)$. We extend $\Delta$ homomorphically to all of $T(L)$, namely $\Delta(x\otimes y) = \Delta(x)\otimes \Delta(y)$ and so on. Explicitly, this means for $x,y \in L$,
\begin{gather*}
\Delta(x\otimes y) = (x \boxtimes 1) \otimes (y\boxtimes1)+(x\boxtimes1)\otimes(1\boxtimes y) + (1\boxtimes x)\otimes (y\boxtimes1) + (1\boxtimes x)\otimes (1\boxtimes y)
\end{gather*}
In the next step we simplify the first term for example as
$$
(x \boxtimes 1) \otimes (y\boxtimes1) = (x\otimes y) \boxtimes 1
$$
I'm assuming 1 in this case means $1\otimes 1$, but why does the above equality hold?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez So is it similarly not valid to write $\Delta(x)\otimes \Delta(y)$? Should this $\otimes$ also be multiplication in $T(L) \boxtimes T(L)$

Comment: I think I agree. In that case, the wikipedia article for tensor algebra has a mistake? Or am I reading it incorrectly? In the "coproduct" section they write $\Delta: x \otimes y \mapsto \Delta(x)\otimes \Delta(y)$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez and later in the discussion of the shuffle product general formula